# Evaluate $\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}} \ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate
>
> $$\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried rationalizing the denominator by twice multiplying, but it didn't do any good. I also tried trig substitutions but that too didn't work out.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I would start with the substitution $x = u^2$.

Comment: the solution contains the elliptic function

Comment: If there is an answer that does not involve elliptic or hypergeometric functions I would very much like to see it.